# How to generate test coverage report in Meteor / Velocity?

Tags: testing, meteor, code-coverage, meteor-velocity

The [Velocity documentation](http://velocity.meteor.com/) mentions test coverage as a primary feature of the framework, but I'm having a hard time finding specific instructions for getting started.

Is there support for test coverage reporting in Meteor / Velocity (either directly or via a third-party package)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't currently do this, but it is on the road map.

This used to work: https://github.com/xolvio/meteor-coverage but it can't with the new mirror approach. I'll update this answer when we get it working again.

Comment: I am also interested in this.  Commenting so I get updated as well.

Comment: Any Updates? Especially considering Meteor 1.3